# Broken pipe issue

Tags: octave

I'm trying to learn machine learning using Octave.

OS: Mac, High Sierra 10.13.3
GNU Octave version: 3.8.0

```
t = [0: 0.01: 0.98];
y1 = sin(2*pi*4*t);
y2 = sin(2*pi*4*t);
plot(t, y1);
hold on;
plot(t, y2, 'r');
figure(1); plot(t,y1);
```

The first time I tried ran the last line I got: "Qt terminal communication error: select() error 9 Bad file descriptor"

After this I got a broken pipe error, I thought I need to plot both the graphs again before trying "figure(1); plot(y,t1);". But, it didn't work.

Checked whois and printed the values of y1, y2 and t; they do exist. So, my questions are:

1. Why am I not able to plot the graphs?
2. How do I solve broken pipe error?
3. How to solve the Qt terminal communication error?

[image: Terminal image]

Comment: Sounds like you have a bad installation of octave. What OS are you using? What version of octave? Why aren't you using the GUI version? Are you sure gnuplot and the usual libraries used for plotting from the terminal version of octave are actually installed?

Comment: from the slider on the right I guess this is bitten apple OS

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou OS: Mac, High Sierra 10.13.3 and GNU Octave version: 3.8.0

Comment: 3.8.0 is five years old! Just install the newest version already. I'm sure it's available on homebrew or something.

Comment: Coursera Machine Learning class is still using this version.

Answer (score 0):

> Coursera's **Machine Learning** class is still using this version of Octave (3.8.0)

Here is what helped me:

run the following the os x terminal:

```
brew uninstall gnuplot
brew install gnuplot --with-qt
```

then create a file in your home directory called `.octaverc` and add the following to it:

`setenv("GNUTERM","qt")`

Relaunch octave-cli

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

simply close the terminal and relaunch it , and this fixes the issue.
This occurred to me as I tried quitting the gnu-plot instead of using close command causing the pipe linked to gnu be broken.